# Mysql coding question

Tags: mysql

Is there an if or if else type statement for mysql.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an if else construct:

```
IF(value == x, 1, 0)
```

This returns 1 if value equals x and 0 otherwise.

Comment: is this to be used inside the mysql coding?

Comment: that's an `IF()` function and different from an `IF` statement. Just pointing out.

Comment: @blah, yes. You can have it as a column in a query. @Ruel: yes. I think this may be what the asker wants, if not, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As JoshD said, yes there is. Here is the reference in the MySQL Online Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

And an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) Statement.

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```